# I can't setText() on another layout file

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, textview

So I have a separate layout file for a navigation, and I want to edit it on a button click. But when I do so, I get the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

The code that I use to define it is:

```
    private TextView tvData;
    private TextView gettingPrices;
    private TextView navTime;
    private TextView title;
    navTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.refreshPricesNav);
    tvData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);
    gettingPrices = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gettingPrices);
    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.navtitle);
```

and the code that executes is here:

```
title.setText("Last Checked" + Datetime());
```

Fixed! Added `navTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.refreshPricesNav);` to onPostExecute

Comment: Hard to say regarding the info you provided. Make sure, that `title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.navtitle);` is definitely called before `title.setText("Last Checked" + Datetime());` and that ID `R.id.navtitle` exists in you layout.xml

Comment: can you post your onCreate() method impl.

Comment: add your layout and java code so that one can easily tell u what the prob is?

Answer (score 2):

your `R.id.navtitle` `TextView` is not available in current layout file.

1. Create method in class where this `TextView` is available
2. make `TextView` `static` so that you can access it from other class also.

Answer (score 0):

You should move all the below code

```
    navTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.refreshPricesNav);
    tvData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);
    gettingPrices = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gettingPrices);
    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.navtitle);
```

to `onCreate` method of that activity. Don't remember to set the view before pasting the above code. You should set the content view as

```
setContentView(R.layout.filename);
```

Replace the `filename` based on your layout name.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what happens where you are calling this line of code

```
title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.navtitle);
```

here, the method  findViewById() returns null, so the **title** is pointing to no where, means  title has no object reference, this happens because   you have nor declared TextView in your current layout file by the id of **navtitle**, so you must have declared this in your current layout or you can use the include http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html tag if you are declaring in some other layout.